# UTL_FILE appends LF to end of file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, utl-file

With my following PLSQL block, I experience a Line Feed character at the end of the file. My expectation is that there will be no line feed.

```
DECLARE
  v_MyFileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  BEGIN
       v_MyFileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIREC','HELLO.TXT','a');
       UTL_FILE.PUT(v_MyFileHandle, '1');
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_MyFileHandle);
 END;
```

The above block outputs a file that looks like:

> 1[LF]

```
DECLARE
  v_MyFileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  BEGIN
       v_MyFileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIREC','HELLO.TXT','a');
       UTL_FILE.PUT(v_MyFileHandle, '1');
       UTL_FILE.PUT(v_MyFileHandle, '2');
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_MyFileHandle);
 END;
```

The above block will produce a file that looks like:

> 12[LF]

How do I prevent the line feed at the end of the file?

Comment: What operating system? If you do an `FFLUSH` and then put your program into a long-running loop without closing the file, what does the file have in it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE` as a workaround. It does not create [LF] on Unix and [CR][LF] on Windows at the end of file.

```
DECLARE
  v_myClob CLOB := '1';
  BEGIN
  DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE( v_myClob, 'MY_DIREC', 'HELLO.TXT');     
 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

After extensive googling, I found that this worked using "wb" for byte mode and put_raw.

```
sBufToWrite := 'line1' || chr(13) || chr(10) || line2' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'line3'; 
sFileName := 'testfile.txt'; 
out_file := utl_file.fopen('DATA_DIRECTORY', sFileName, 'wb'); 
utl_file.put_raw(out_file, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sBufToWrite)); 
utl_file.fclose(out_file);
```